# Weird sound in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio

I am getting the problem similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/333880/what-is-the-source-of-this-funny-noise-in-windows). The weird sound keeps playing randomly and I don't know how to get it resolved in Windows 7 since Windows 7 doesn't has a dog animation in search explorer.

Comment: the question you link to mentions a certain spyware (Juicy Steaks Poker) that makes a similar noise--perhaps you could try scanning your computer with anti-spyware software?

Comment: Please describe the sound.

Comment: the sound is sometimes a *click*, sometimes a *door closed*.

Comment: randomly , that might best describe the running or stopping of background processes. Check what White Pheonix wrote, then play the sounds for "open Program" and "close Program" , usually they are off. A theme change will change the sounds. Other ones that could seem random is "system notifications" and if everything is going badly :-) "critical stop" "default beep" and "device disconnect"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that "click" you're talking about is the "Complete Navigation" sound that happens when you visit a website in IE (though sometimes some programs use IE as a base for some of their Windows, and therefore you'll hear this clicking outside of IE too).

To stop that clicking noise:

1. Go to Start menu --> Control Panel
2. View by: Small/Large Icons
3. Open the Sound control panel.
4. Click on the Sounds tab.
5. Scroll to the Windows Explorer section and find the "Complete Navigation" item.
6. Under the Sounds dropdown menu (located below the "Play Windows Sound" checkbox), choose (None), which is the first item in that dropdown menu.
7. Click OK.

That should stop the annoying clicking.  I also suggest switching to a different browser, such as Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: First thing I ever do on any Windows system is disable that moronic "complete navigation" sound.